# In Teradata, with SQL, how do I compare multiple dates and select the latest date?

Tags: sql, teradata, greatest-n-per-group

Below is the table and the required output.

I want to select the ***ID***,***STATUS*** and ***DATE*** where the ***DATE*** is the latest date. If the ***DATE*** is the same, only select the records where ***STATUS*** = **A**.

I need to able to do this in Teradata with SQL.

**Table:**

```
ID        STATUS        DATE
5550500     A          11/02/2016
5550500     I          8/08/2008
5551688     A          23/08/2013
5551688     I          23/08/1997
5551688     I          23/08/2013
5551966     I          18/10/1999
5551966     I          24/10/2003
5551966     I          10/11/1997
5551966     I          2/09/2014
```

**Required Output:**

```
ID        STATUS        DATE
5550500    A           11/02/2016
5551688    A           23/08/2013
5551966    I           2/09/2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata supports a syntax extension to filter directly on the result of a Windowed Aggregate Function without need for a Derived Table:

```
select *
from tab
QUALIFY -- similar to HAVING after GROUP BY
   row_number() -- or RANK to return multiple rows with the same (max date & status)
   over (partition by id 
         order by date desc, status) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `row_number` with a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select id, status, date, 
           row_number() over (partition by id 
                              order by date desc, status) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks I tested the code out and seems to work nicely,  could you explain how it works?

Comment: @Tikkaty -- This establishes a row number partitioned by the id (or grouped by the id) and the ordering by the most recent date and for ties, then by status.  Then you just take the first per group (`where rn = 1`) and you have your list.